# How to set default value in material-UI select box in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-design, material-ui, jss

I am using [Select box](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/) from material-ui

I want to show "select the value" option by default selected but after that user is not able to select this option.

```
<FormControl required className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="circle">Circle</InputLabel>
    <Select
      value={circle}
      onChange={event => handleInput(event, "circle")}
      input={<Input name="circle" id="circle" />}
    >
      <MenuItem value="" disabled>
        <em>select the value</em>
      </MenuItem>

      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  <FormHelperText>Some important helper text</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```

Current code on sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xoylmlj1qp

I want to make like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wc1mxdto/

---

### Update

I changed the state `20` to blank string in circle

```
form: {
  searchValue: "",
  circle: '',
  searchCriteria: ""
}
```

now expected output should be dropdown should show "please select value" but  currently it showing this
[image]

Comment: make it stateful

Comment: already a state ful i aleady pass the state value

Comment: your sandbox isn't updated

Comment: see the first select box..which have option "select value" but it is not by default selected

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xoylmlj1qp

Comment: @SakhiMansoor any way to do this . ?

Comment: Yes I am writing the answer

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to provide correct `MenuItem` value in state to be matched on render.

Here is the working codesandbox: [Default Select Value Material-UI](https://codesandbox.io/s/9o51969rlp)

Comment: sorry it is not a correct answer . instead of `20` if I am passing `""` (blank) string it should select "please select value" as shown in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wc1mxdto/

Comment: It is already showing it as default value if you pass empty string. Please elaborate your issue

Comment: please see update Question.I am updating more to clear more

Comment: see updated code i used `shrink` property in first select box https://codesandbox.io/s/j7kwpnp593

Comment: not when I run application it should show please select value

Comment: see this fiddle when I run or open this link it show's "select your option" https://jsfiddle.net/wc1mxdto/2/ but after user select options but not select this option "select your option" because that is disable

Comment: Updated my codesandbox.You need renderValue as creating a reactElement in select other than menuItems

Comment: working so this select value is  "select value" ?? correct  ? for UI it is correct but logically it is not correct .because if I take this is `required` it is alway true..:(

Comment: Your example is hard to follow. Using some meaningful names instead of `<Abc/>` and `test` would be better.

Comment: Sample is broken: "_typeof is not a function"

Answer (score 28):

You can just pass the `displayEmpty` into select

```js
<Select
    id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
    displayEmpty
    value={select}
    onChange={handleChange}
>
```

and define the menuItem like

```js
<MenuItem value=""><Put any default Value which you want to show></MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thank you. Was scratching my head for a while. Now I am scratching more wondering why would I ever not want that option?

Comment: This thing is a mess, especially when used with a shrink label.

Answer (score 18):

As React introduced **React-Hooks**, you just need to pass your default value in React.useState() as React.useState(10).

```
export default function CustomizedSelects() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(10);// <--------------(Like this).
  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
      <FormControl className={classes.margin}>
        <Select
          value={age}
          className={classes.inner}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<BootstrapInput name="currency" id="currency-customized-select" />}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question in the title *how to set a default value*. This solution sets the value fixed. Meaning, if you don't use state, the user can't change the value.

Answer (score 5):

```js
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel id="uni">UNI</InputLabel>
  <Select
    key={value}
    defaultValue={value}
    labelId="uni"
    id="uni"
    name="uni"
    onBlur={onChange}
    label="uni"
  >
    {unis.map((u, i) => (
      <MenuItem value={u.value} key={i}>
        {u.label}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

Comment: Could you please add a description to your answer about _how_ and _why_ the code snippet you've provided solves the problem? In other words: what is the root cause of the problem here, and how does your code snippet solve that?

Comment: The first solution in line providing an answer to the question in the title *how to set a default value*.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the **defaultValue** attribute of select.
You can refer to the [Material UI Select API Docs](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) to know more.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';

import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

const Selector = () => {
    const [Value, setValue] = useState("1");    //    "1" is the default value in this scenario. Replace it with the default value that suits your needs.
    const handleValueChange = event => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <FormControl>
            <InputLabel id="Input label">Select</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId= "Input label"
                    id= "Select"
                    value= {Value}
                    defaultValue= {Value}
                    onChange= {handleValueChange}
                >
                    <MenuItem value="1">Item1</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="2">Item2</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="3">Item3</MenuItem>
                </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
};

export default Selector;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the Select Api of Material UI [here](https://material-ui.com/api/select/), you could do it easily.

1. As explained above, you need to pass the default value in your state variable:

```js
const [age, setAge] = React.useState(10);// <--------------(Like this).
```

2. Set displayEmpty to true:

> If true, a value is displayed even if no items are selected.
> In order to display a meaningful value, a function should be passed to the renderValue prop which returns the value to be displayed when no items are selected. You can only use it when the native prop is false (default).

```js
<Select 
  displayEmpty
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I applied a function directly to onChange so I had something like this:

```
export default function CustomizedSelects() {
const classes = useStyles();
const [age, setAge] = React.useState(10);

return (
  <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
    <FormControl className={classes.margin}>
      <Select
        value={age}
        className={classes.inner}
        onChange={(event) => setAge(event.target.value)}
        input={<BootstrapInput name="currency" id="currency-customized-select" />}
    >
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
</form>
```

);
}

I also had a separate button to clear select value (or select the default empty value). All was working, the select value was set correctly, except the Select component did not animate to its default form - when no value is selected. I fixed the problem by moving onChange to a handleChange separate function as it is in the code example @B4BIPIN is presenting.

I am not an expert in React and still learning and this was a good lesson. I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: This will trigger an error with TypeScript though, as event.target.value will be unknown

Answer (score 0):

Take a list of objects you want to display in the Select dropdown and initialise it using useState. Use the state now to show the value and update the state on the change of the dropdown.

```
const ackList = [
  {
    key: 0,
    value: "Not acknowledged",
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    value: "Acknowledged",
  },
];

function AcknowledgementList() {
//state to initialise the first from the list
  const [acknowledge, setAcknowledge] = useState(ackList[1]);

//update the state's value on change
  const handleChange2 = (event) => {
    setAcknowledge(ackList[event.target.value]);
  };
  return (
            <TextField
              select
              fullWidth
              value={acknowledge.key} 
              onChange={handleChange2}
              variant="outlined"
            >
              {ackList.map((ack) => (
                <MenuItem key={ack.key} value={ack.key}>
                  {ack.value}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>

    );

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your answer. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is all to do with some pretty poor coding on the part of the MUI folks, where on several components, they have magic strings and really are doing silly things.

Let's take a look at the state here:

```
const [age, setAge] = React.useState('3');
```

You can see that we are having to specify the VALUE as a string. Indeed the data type that the Select control takes is a string | undefined. So the fact we are having to use a number value as a string is the source of confusion.

So how does that work?

It is all to do with the MenuItem component. Let's take a look:

```
<MenuItem value={1}>First Choice</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={2}>Second Choice</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={3}>Third Choice</MenuItem>
```

You can see that we are indeed having to specify the VALUE of the MenuItem as a number.

So in this case, specifying '3' as the State value, as a string, will select the Third Choice on load.

You can set the VALUE in the Select control as the state value.

Don't forget, when handling the onChange event, that you will need to convert the event.target.value to string.

Answer (score 0):

1. I use the localstorage to get the information that i need for mi component
2. i create a state to save the information that i will use in the select value
3. if i have a previous value en the storage, i will get when a render mi component (useEffect) and save it into the useState.
4. I create the MUI select. whit the current value.

```
const rsStorage: { razonSocial: string, razonSocialId: number } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rs") || "[]");

const [rs, setRs] = useState<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (rsStorage && rsStorage.razonSocialId) {
        setRs(rsStorage.razonSocialId.toString());
      }
    }, []);

    <InputLabel id="lmlMotivo">Razón social</InputLabel>
    <Select
     labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
     id="demo-simple-select-standard"
     value={rs}
     onChange={handleChangeRazonSocial}
     >
      {
        mapeoRazonesSociales()
      }
    </Select>
```